# Validar el registro en bdd

Tags: php

Tengo un problema en el momento de registrar un usuario. Cuando registro un usuario por segunda vez, sale el mensaje de error "Usuario registrado" pero igual lo agrega a la bdd.
¿Qué puedo hacer para que no pase eso?

Gracias.

Código php

```
<?php 

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $correo = $_POST['correo'];
    $perfil = $_POST['perfil'];

    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","formbd");

    $insertar = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,apellido,usuario,pass,correo,perfil)VALUES('$nombre','$apellido','$usuario','$pass','$correo','$perfil')";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario'";
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo = '$correo'";

    $result = $conexion -> query($sql);
    $result2 = $conexion -> query($sql2);
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$insertar);

    if(!$resultado)
    {
        echo "<h4 align=center><font color=\"#FF0000\">Error al registrarse </font></h4>";
        $resultado = false;
    }
    elseif($result -> num_rows > 0)
    {
        echo "<h4 align=center><font color=\"#FF0000\">Error al registrarse </font></h4>";
        echo "<h5 align=center><font color=\"#FF0000\">El usuario ya existe</font></h5>";
        $resultado = false;

    }
    elseif($result2 -> num_rows > 0)
    {
        echo "<h4 align=center><font color=\"#FF0000\">Error al registrarse </font></h4>";
        echo "<h5 align=center><font color=\"#FF0000\">El correo ya existe</font></h5>";
        $resultado = false;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<h4 align=center><font color=\"#008000\">Registrado correctamente</font></h4>";
        $resultado = true;
    }



    mysqli_close($conexion);
```

?>

Comment: primer punto, tu campo usuario en la base de datos debería ser unique, para que desde el gestor de la base de datos se impida tener ese registro duplicado

Comment: Corregido, gracias por tu comentario.

Answer (score 0):

En vez de hacer eso, simplifique las querys de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT usuario,correo FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND correo = '$correo';
```

Yo usaría sentencias preparadas para evitar problemas de sql injection, pero si aun asi prefiere hacerlo de esta manera ejecute primero esa query, después, compruebe si las columnas existen o no con un `if`, y si no existen pues ya ahí ejecuta la otra query para introducir los datos.